# <data> customs problems with element-list

Tags: list

I would like to preface that my knowledge on this matter is very limited, so I'm relying on Chat GPT for assistance.

I have an issue with style customization (I was consistently using  because the forum where I need to place it filters out most attributes, so only  works [forumfree platform]). Once I insert the customization attributes to be called in the CSS, the list elements become unclickable.

```
 .equip {display: flex}
 .left-column {width: 30%}
 .right-column {width: 70%}
 .list-item {cursor: pointer}
 .list-item:hover {border-bottom: 1px solid #000; padding-bottom: 5px}
 .active {font-weight: bold}
```

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() { 
 var listItems = document.querySelectorAll('.list-item'); 
 var rightColumn = document.querySelector('.right-column'); 
 
 listItems.forEach(function(item) { 
 item.addEventListener('click', function() { 
 // Rimuove la classe 'active' da tutti gli elementi della lista 
 listItems.forEach(function(li) { 
 li.classList.remove('active'); 
 }); 
 
 // Aggiunge la classe 'active' all'elemento selezionato 
 this.classList.add('active'); 
 
 // Aggiorna il contenuto nella colonna di destra 
 var info = this.getAttribute('data-info'); 
 rightColumn.innerHTML = '<p>' + info + '</p>'; 
 }); 
 }); 
 }); 
 </script>
```

```
<div class="equip">
 <div class="left-column">
 
<ul>
 <li class="list-item" data-info="Informazioni oggetto 1">Oggetto 1</li>
 <li class="list-item" data-info="Informazioni oggetto 2">Oggetto 2</li>
 <li class="list-item" data-info="Informazioni oggetto 3">Oggetto 3</li>
 <li class="list-item" data-info="Informazioni oggetto 4">Oggetto 4</li>
 <li class="list-item" data-info="Informazioni oggetto 5">Oggetto 5</li>
 </ul>
 </div>
 <div class="right-column">
 <p>Seleziona un oggetto dalla lista a sinistra per visualizzarne le informazioni.</p>
 </div>
 </div>
```

I need the customization to be modifiable through CSS and to be directly called in the HTML with a single script that works with all the style customizations, without having to write 50 different scripts with separate classes for 50 style customizations.